# How to create a new partition in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, partitioning, fdisk

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04. It's showing the whole hard drive as single partition. I need to split the drive into different partitions.

How can I accomplish this, preferably via the terminal?

Comment: Do you have live ISO image and bootable disk ?

Comment: ya i'm having iso image.

Comment: i'm having live iso image if i'm using the live image whether i need to install os newly again?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the standard procedure: boot from a Live CD/DVD/USB/whatever, use your favourite partitioning tool, done.

For partitioning you can use GParted (GUI and my favourite), parted (CLI), fdisk, cdisk or cfdisk. I haven't used any tool other than GParted (which comes with the ISO) to resize and reformat partitions. If you desperately need to use CLI, I can't help.